# combining falcon 40b instruct with langchain

Tags: nlp, chatbot, langchain, large-language-model, falcon

I want to create a local LLM using falcon 40b instruct model and combine it with lanchain so I can give it a pdf or some resource to learn from so I can query it ask it questions, learn from it and ultimately be able to derive insights from the pdf report from an Excel sheet.

For now, I just want to load a pdf using langchain and have the falcon-40b-instruct model as the agent.

I want to build an llm where I can make it interact with my own data using langchain.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFaceHub

llm = HuggingFaceHub(
repo_id=model_name,
task="text-generation",
model_kwargs={
"max_new_tokens": 512,
"top_k": 30,
"temperature": 0.1,
"repetition_penalty": 1.03
},
huggingfacehub_api_token="hf_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
)
```

I reached the following stage:

```
from langchain_community.chat_models.huggingface import ChatHuggingFace
llm = ChatHuggingFace(llm=llm)
```

yet I get this error:

> HfHubHTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url

I am doing do this to be able to run the following:

```
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
llm=llm,
retriever=vector_db.as_retriever()
)
```

What am I missing and is there a way to be able to do this fully local like doing the falcon model and pass it to ChatHuggingFace?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by local. But 401 usually mean you don't have access. Can you try standalone request to hf hub and check if it's working with token you're using. That should give you insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message of `HfHubHTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url` indicates that you don't have access to `endpoint` service from HuggingFace > https://huggingface.co/inference-endpoints.

As you want to run *everything* locally, here's an example, using `HuggingFacePipeline` function

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, pipeline

# model_id = "tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct"  # this model is too large to run on Nvidia 4090 with 16G ram
model_id = "gpt2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
pipeline = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_new_tokens=200,
)


from langchain_community.llms.huggingface_pipeline import HuggingFacePipeline
llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipeline)


from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
template = """Question: {question}

Answer: Let's think step by step."""
prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)

chain = prompt | llm
question = "Tell me about Italy"

print(chain.invoke({"question": question}))
```

Comment: thank you so much, i am now able to run this on colab pro.
i have one more thing to add which is that the following QA take like 10 to 15 minutes to generate an answer from one single document. how can i make it faster? i am using colab pro with the A100 GPU and High Ram option.

qa_chain_mr = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm,
    retriever=vector_db.as_retriever(),
    chain_type="refine"
)

Comment: There are 2 things to consider. (1) the LLM. I would recommend you can try `gpt4all` which uses `mistral` model. I used it in production and its quality is good enough surprisingly. All running locally for privacy in enterprise. (2) what VectorStore are you using?. In term of performance troubleshooting, you can enable `debug` mode to view where exactly takes too much time during execution